# Hashicorp Vault - Can a deleted key be retrieved back?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to retrieve a deleted key from the Hashicorp Vault tool that is used to store secrets.

I tried to delete a single value, but it seems to have deleted a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my answer.  This is not supported by Vault.  The recommendation is to back up the underlying datastore.  It is advisable to be careful while deleting any keys from Vault.

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2018, the K/V (v2) secret backend is versioned, and so can restore deleted keys.

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault-0-10